# My localhost:8000 just stopped to work. How can I get it back?

Tags: python, django, localhost

I am using ubuntu 20.04 I do not know if it matters, but I tried to see if the 8000 PORT was being used before I tried to run, and it was not.

I was working on my Django project, running my localhost:8000 last night, but it stopped. Everything I have is a infinite loading. So, I returned today and I could not run my project. I do not know what happened. So, I started a new branch from the working code to check if it stopped because of me, but nothing changed.

I've tried to restart and turn off my computer, I've erased my cache, I've tried in 4 different browsers (chrome, firefox, opera, brave), I've tried to re-run, and I've tried to use my local IP, but nothing happened.

I am expecting to run again my project and I do not know if is related to my computer.

P.S: I am using docker.

```
django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    command: python /app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: If it says the port is already used, you can use this command to kill the process `sudo fuser -k 8000/tcp`

Comment: It is hard to tell without any code or traceback output. But, at least to check if the problem relies within your project code, you could create another base project and run the development server to see if it works. In case is does, then your project probably has something that is not loading properly.

Comment: Are you using docker or any other virtualisation technologies?

Comment: Yes, I am! Docker is calling the "runserver".

Comment: In order to access the webserver running in the container, in a browser on your machine, you have to expose the port it's running on. I'm not sure how you managed to access it previously though.